# Custom footnote without horizontal rule

Tags: pdftex, footnotes, footmisc

I would like to have a custom footnote(blfootnote) without horizontal rule, but when I use footnote command I needed horizontal rule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
\def\footnoterulewidth{\textwidth}

%\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
%  \kern-3\p@
%  \hrule\@width\footnoterulewidth
%  \kern2.6\p@}

\makeatother
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
%\renewcommand*\footnoterule{0pt}
  \endgroup
}


\begin{document}

Some text\blfootnote{A footnote without marker} and some more text
\lipsum[1-5]
Some text\footnote{A standard footnote}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want. I get a footnote at the bottom of the page with no line above but you also talk about a "marker". To me this is the number of the footnote in both the text and at the start of the footnote itself. If there is no "marker" in the text or with the footnote how is the reader supposed to know what is going on?

Comment: You could use a bottom float, either figure or table or create a new float type using the newfloat or float packages.  Putting more than one on a page/column might be difficult.